# Potential hibernate version issue: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.setListener(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)

Tags: hibernate, grails, intellij-idea

I'm trying to debug a Grails project (from another developer) with Intellij and running into this error:

```
ERROR org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing
the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization
of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean
'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.setListener(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean
property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.setListener(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

From researching forums, I suspect that the loader is referring to a class that exists in Hibernate-3 and not Hibernate-4. I'm using IntelliJ's Hibernate plug-in but I can't see why Hibernate-4 is being loaded.

When I create a dummy Grails app, however, I don't run into this error.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I was supposed to manually specify the version of Hibernate via Intellij's Project Structure dialog box (on Mac it's through File -> Project Structure). Click on *Dependencies* and you'll see something like below:

[image]

If you double-click on Hibernate, you'll see something like the following:

[image]

There, click on *Change Version* and specify the desired version of the library.

Note that the change also required me to delete *lib* and *target* folders, and rerun IntelliJ to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `grails dependency-report` . It will generate a dependency report like below.

```
+--- org.grails.plugins:hibernate:3.6.10.18
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:3.6.10.Final
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-core:3.1.3.RELEASE
|         \--- org.javassist:javassist:3.17.1-GA
|         \--- javax.transaction:jta:1.1
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:3.1.3.RELEASE
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate:3.1.3.RELEASE
|         \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core:3.1.3.RELEASE
|              \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support:3.1.3.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-orm:4.0.7.RELEASE
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-simple:3.1.3.RELEASE
|    \--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:3.6.10.Final
|    \--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.0.0.GA
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:4.1.0.Final
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:3.6.10.Final
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:3.2.0.Final
+--- org.grails.plugins:database-migration:1.4.0
|    \--- org.liquibase:liquibase-core:2.0.5
+--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.3
|    \--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.2
|    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6
+--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3
```

This will list you all the depedencies your project is using. Search for hibernate4 and see if any of your plugins is referring to hibernate4. Remove or upgrade the plugin to use hibernate3.

Comment: _grails dependency-report_ is certainly useful for future reference. Thank you for taking the time to reply. In my case, however, finding out the dependencies on Hibernate 3 wouldn't have sufficed as the library wasn't being made available at the first place.